# Why authorities didn't change retina scan of building after CEO got kidnapped?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In Entrapment (1999), here CEO of Petronas Towers got kidnapped in public to get his retina scan used to enter into vault contained a computer which can access 8 billion dollars.

[image]

Here thugs stealing his retina scan of him.

[image]

Why authorities still didn't change retina scan of building after CEO got kidnapped?

Comment: How exactly would you "change the retina scan of [the] building?"  This isn't as simple as changing your password - the CEO can't change his retina pattern on demand.

Comment: what about 8 billion dollars in vault? then?

Comment: There was no 8 billion dollars in a vault... **ever**.

Comment: Vault?  What vault?  It was a bank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The CEO wasn't kidnapped.

He was sprayed with [**Mace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_(spray)) which meant that he had to get his eyes examined for possible damage.

During that examination, his retinal scan was captured **without his knowledge**.

So, there was no reason to change the retinal scan access as no-one knew it had been compromised.

---

> vault where 8 billion of money stored.

There was no vault with **money stored in it**.

The vault contained a computer with access to the Bank's headquarters which they needed access to.

Using that access, they could manipulate the computer to

> transfer relatively small amounts of money from hundreds of corporations all over South East Asia into her account.

Which totalled $8 billion.

Comment: I agree. The guy never got kidnapped, so no one thought his security access had been compromised, and the purpose of the exercise was to get ready to hack their way in and steal money electronically; not to physically remove tons of cash from a vault.

Comment: @Paulie_D NO WHERE it mentioned he got examined for eyes, by spraying I thought he is getting kidnapped.